# Realtime read of Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, android

The problem with the program works in real time.
For example: getevent
But when I try to read the data coming out of the process, the exec gives their parts at least 4096 bytes!

For example:

- if getevent returned **1000 bytes** of text that:  **stdout.available () == 0**
- if getevent returned **4000 bytes** of text that:  **stdout.available () == 0**
- if getevent returned 4096 bytes of text that:  stdout.available () == 4096
- if getevent returned 8192 bytes of text that:  stdout.available () == 8192
- if getevent returned **10000 bytes** of text that:  **stdout.available () == 8192**

If to use stdout.read() the function will wait until 4096*n bytes or until getevent is closed.

How do I read the data that come in real time instead of waiting until 4096 will be dialed bytes?

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "system/bin/sh"});
DataOutputStream stdin = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
stdin.writeBytes("getevent\n");
InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
int read;
String out = new String();
while(true){
  read = stdout.read(buffer);
  out += new String(buffer, 0, read);
  System.out.println("MYLOG: "+(new String(buffer, 0, read)));
}
```

I find this buffed in documentation!

> **Copies the InputStream into the OutputStream, until the end of the
>   stream has been reached. This method uses a buffer of 4096 kbyte.**

**>> [Documentation](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/CopiestheInputStreamintotheOutputStreamuntiltheendofthestreamhasbeenreachedThismethodusesabufferof4096kbyte.htm)**

Comment: The javadoc for [Process](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process.html) indicates that you should either 1) read the process's `stdout` and `stderr` streams simultaneously on two threads or 2) use [`redirectErrorStream(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream(boolean)) to merge the streams. If you don't do either, the process may block: `"If these streams are not read, the target process may block while it awaits buffer space."` Perhaps ignoring `stderr` is preventing you from reading `stdout` in realtime?

Comment: In your code, `stdout` is a `InputStream`, which will [always return `0`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) from it's `available()`-method. Also, this class you linked is nothing official and uses a buffer of 4KB, you use a buffer of 1B.

Comment: @user113215 Checked. Did not help. 4096 * n bytes ...

Comment: @LukasKnuth function calls the system, not me. As standard it uses 4K and I do not know how to change it. `Most clients should wrap their input stream with BufferedInputStream. Callers that do only bulk reads may omit buffering.` [http://developer..../InputStream.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html)

Comment: I don't see where you're using this method anywhere. Casting that aside, the method takes a third parameter with the size of the buffer to be used.

Comment: @LukasKnuth True. I do not use it. Give an example of how to use it in my code? Most likely, this option uses the internal functions such as getInputStream () to which I have access.

Comment: You linked the source, I suppose you read it. What is your actual *specific* problem with the implementation?

Comment: @LukasKnuth I need a direct reading stream without the system buffer in 4KB

Comment: In the code you posted, there is no 4KB buffer.

Comment: @LukasKnuth ...... System code tree:  getInputStream() => InputStream => copyStreams(...) ! I used getInputStream(), he user prototype InputStream, InputStream used function copyStreams, where buffer! And I have a result from buffer, The system uses ITSELF! If the task was so simple - I would, and did not ask here....

Comment: The `InputStream` you get from the `Process`-object should be unbuffered. If the system does buffer it, you can't do much about it. But, since the rest of the data will be available when the process terminates, I don't really see a problem with your "real time" reading. It will always *feel* like real-time.

Comment: @LukasKnuth `when the process terminates` process is not terminate!!! He live 1 hour, 2 hours, 5 hours, 5 days, 10 days, year and not terminate! This is the essence! When the process is not terminated - for him somewhere in the system buffer is used!

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of this is that the external application is buffering its output.  This is pretty typical for an application that is writing to its "standard output".  The solution is to modify the external application so that it "flushes" its output at the appropriate time.

There is nothing in your Java code that will cause it to delay if there is data that is available to be read.  In particular, use of a DataOutputStream won't cause this.

---

It should also be noted that `available()` does not give reliable information.  If you read the API documentation carefully, you will see that a return value of `N` only means that a simultaneous attempt to read more than N bytes *might* block.  A thread cannot call both `available()` and `read()` simultaneously, so by the time you come to use the information supplied by `available()` it could be out of date.

Comment: `The most likely cause of this is that the external application is buffering its output.` Terminal-emulator works great... `There is nothing in your Java code...` [link1](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/CopiestheInputStreamintotheOutputStreamuntiltheendofthestreamhasbeenreachedThismethodusesabufferof4096kbyte.htm) [link2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#count) no comments...